# Xamarin Datatrigger messing with padding/margin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I got these two buttons with messed up padding. The selected button doesn't get the padding it's suppoed to have and gets reset to 0 or something.

https://gyazo.com/93bb69132b8b9c30bd7c7ac5c43bff7e
This is how it currently look like, how do I make the selected and non-selected to look the same?

I ried to set the padding again in the datatrigger but that didn't change anything.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,5,10,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Text="KGA" CommandParameter="KGA" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="KgaButton" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Padding="10,5,10,5"
           Command="{Binding SelectCompanyCommand}">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding CompanyButton1}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"  Value="Default" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="Default" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5"></Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding CompanyButton1}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"  Value="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <Button  Text="CBL" CommandParameter="CBL" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CblButton" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Padding="10,5,10,5"
           Command="{Binding SelectCompanyCommand}" >
            <Button.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding CompanyButton2}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"  Value="Default" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="Default" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5"></Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding CompanyButton2}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"  Value="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5"></Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

    </Grid>




 public bool CompanyButton1
        {
            get => companyButton1;
            set
            {
                companyButton1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: As you can read on the [Data Triggers docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers): `Data triggers use data binding to monitor another control to cause the Setters to get called.` So you must check what are `CompanyButton21` and `CompanyButton2`, if they're controls of the view, you must bind them via `x:Reference`.

Comment: What do you mean? They are buttons?

Comment: what are `CompanyButton1` and `CompanyButton2` ?

Comment: It's just the bool it is bound to. Added it to my post at the end

Comment: Plese read again my first answer and the official docs link i share, you **can't** bind a trigger to a property on your viewmodel or code behind, you can only bind a data trigger to another control vía `x:Reference`

Comment: If you want to change the Button's style, then apply these styles to all button in this page, you could refer to this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#applying-a-trigger-using-a-style, I test your demo, it is not changed anything in this button, maybe you could share your demo?

Comment: Hey @LeonLu-MSFT Can't share demo as it part of a much larger application, too big. Will look into testing applying it to all styles

Comment: @FabriBertani Hey,I see. So I can't bind it to my bool there. How should I fix my code, I do understand what you mean, but can you give an example on what you mean? Not sure how to fix it

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT This is the stackoverflow I used and here they do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446103/modify-button-background-through-triggers-xamarin-forms

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry the issue was figured out a couple of days ago. If I changed it to handle from the code-behind via x:name instead.